# Is iCloud Photo Library setting on OS X device-wide or per local Photo Library?

Tags: macos, photos

My wife has A TON of photos and I don't want all of them getting pushed to iCloud if I have iCloud Photo Library turned on. If I have a local `System Library` for current photos and an archive library for older photos will the Photos app try to push the archived photos up to iCloud when the archive library is opened?